# Why is removing hard-linked files so slow in Lion?

Tags: uti

```
$ ln src/* dir
$ rm dir/*
```

If `src/` contains a few hundred files, the `rm` operation takes many minutes. If I open the directory in Finder, I can see the files vanishing one by one. This operation used to be virtually instantaneous in Snow Leopard, but is excruciatingly slow in Lion. If I *copy* the files instead of hard-linking them, removing them is still instantaneous.

Can anybody tell me what has changed to warrant this slowness?

Comment: I can't reproduce this here. rm takes hardly any time at all. Is another process accessing the drive at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured it out. It seems to be Mobile Time Machine that's causing the slowdown. Apparently it's dutifully taking a backup of the files while they're being deleted. If the files are "original", it can simply *move* them to the Time Machine vault, but if they're links it has to *copy* them instead, which takes much longer.